# the time bar of powerlevel9k go to the second line

Tags: themes, windows-subsystem-for-linux, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I'm trying to set up wsl in my computer

and I install the powerlevel9k theme for it.

But the system time bar seems doesn't work correctly.

the time bar went to the second line, which is my command line.

when I type something, what I type will cover the original text(i.e. time status)

I wonder if there has anything I do is wrong

or it's just a bug?

Btw, in my `.zshrc` I didn't edit anything except `ZSH_THEME`.

And I apologize for this horrible color in my picture :(

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Powerlevel9k has been discontinued and superseded by Powerlevel10k. Try installing Powerlevel10k and see if it fixes the issue.